# Can I mix OpenGL versions?

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I'm going to start implementing OpenGL 3 into my application. I currently am using OpenGL 1.1 but I wanted to keep some of it due to problems if I attempt to change the code but I wanted to change some of my drawing code to a faster version of OpenGL. If I do things like bind textures in OpenGL 1.1 can I draw the texture in OpenGL 3?

Answer (score 4):

Mixing OpenGL versions isn't as easy as it used to be. In OpenGL 3.0, a lot of the old features were marked as "deprecated" and were removed in 3.1. However, since OpenGL 3.2, there are two profiles defined: **Core** and **Compatibility**. The OpenGL context is created with respect to such a profile. In compatibility profile,
all the deprecated (and in core profiles removed) stuff is still availbale, and it can be mixed as well. You can even mix a custom vertex shader with the fixed-function fragment processing or vice versa.

The problem here is that it is not grequired that implementors actually provide support for the compatibility profile. On MacOS X, OpenGL 3.x and 4.x are supported in core profile only.

In you specific example, binding textures will work in all cases, since that funtctionality exists unmodified in all versions from 1.1 to 4.3 (and is likely to do so in the near future). However, most of your drawing calls are likely to be not available in the newer core profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Omg.. opengl 1.1 is from 1997! Do yourself a favor and get rid of the fixed-function pipeline stuff and adapt to OpenGL 4.x. However, you can try
    #version 420 core

in your shader.

Comment: OpenGL 4 is newer, but I'm worried it's too new.

Comment: My laptop is only 1 year old and only handles 3.0 :P. I can never develop with 3.1 +

Comment: Macs (late 2012) support only upto OpenGL 3.2.